# MYSQL Query with distinct and max

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a mysql query which will select all rows that contain "joe" in either the "to" or "from" column. It needs to be distinct among the "to" and "from" columns, which means that it does not matter what order the names appear in. i.e. "joe", "bob" should be treated as the same as "bob", "joe". If there are duplicates among a pair of names, choose the one with the max id. The final table should also be sorted by id descending. For example, running the query on the below table:

Before:

```
id  to    from     
---|-----|------
1  | joe | bob | 
2  | bob | hal |
3  | joe | joe |
4  | sue | joe |
5  | bob | bob |
6  | bob | joe |
7  | hal | hal |
8  | joe | bob |
```

After:

```
id  to    from     
---|-----|------
8  | joe | bob | 
4  | sue | joe |
3  | joe | joe |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a GROUP BY where you group by (from, to) sorted in alphabetical order:

```
SELECT id, `from`, `to`
FROM yourtable
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE `from` = 'joe' OR `to` = 'joe'
    GROUP BY LEAST(`from`, `to`), GREATEST(`from`, `to`)
)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc622/3)

Comment: Am I misreading the question - but is not the answer to the OP's original question as simple as SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table WHERE to='joe' OR from='joe'

Comment: @AdrianCornish: That returns 5 rows instead of the 3 rows that the OP desires. See for yourself: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc622/5

Comment: You are correct - I was wrong - Sorry was reading his question rather than looking at his expected result set - now I see the reason for the GROUP BY

Comment: I sometimes fancy myself a SQL expert - had never dealt with `LEAST` and `GREATEST`. Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Hrmm...I can get close with:

```
SELECT inside.id, inside.`to` , inside.`from` 
FROM (
  SELECT MAX( id ) id,  `to` ,  `from` 
  FROM people
  WHERE  `to` =  'joe'
  OR  `from` =  'joe'
  GROUP BY  `to` ,  `from`
)inside
ORDER BY inside.id DESC
```

But that doesn't quite give the results you want because it still has dupes when the to and from are swapped.

I was trying with some `UNION`'s, but that actually ends up complicating the problem because it ends up creating more unique columns (I would swap the order of `to` and `from` to get all the joe's into the same column). Once you've got the right unique rows without taking into account that `to` and `from` matters, it's harder getting it back to where `to` and `from` **don't** matter.

Maybe this will get you started while I puzzle over it some more.